# Would compiler put jump table at the end of function?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, x86

For example, this is an assembly with jump table

```
movl    $5, -4(%ebp)
cmpl    $10, -4(%ebp)
ja  L13
movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
sall    $2, %eax
movl    L14(%eax), %eax
jmp *%eax
.section .rdata,"dr"
.align 4
L14:
.long   L13
.long   L3
.long   L4
.long   L5
.long   L6
.long   L7
.long   L8
.long   L9
.long   L10
.long   L11
.long   L12
.text
L3:
movl    $LC0, (%esp)
call    _printf
jmp L2
...
```

My question is, is that possible for compiler like GCC or ICC to put jump table at the end of the function instead of in the middle of function?

Comment: Depends on the function really. If there is a dependency most likely it will be placed in the middle. It can really only be placed at the end if it's the last thing executed by a function (that isn't inlined).

Comment: Where the compiler places the JMP table is generally a matter of convenience for the compiler; whoever wrote it had reasons for placing it there.   It doesn't matter a lot unless you are really concerned about interference of different cache lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table won't end up in the middle of the function. If you look carefully you may notice this line:

```
.section .rdata,"dr"
```

It tells the assembler to put the following data into the section named ".rdata".

And the following `.text` tells the assembler to switch back to the .text section. So the function code will actually be placed contiguously (in `.text`), and the jump table will be stored separately (in `.rdata`).